# How do you animate when you press the power button to lock the screen on s10?

Tags: samsung, lock-screens, samsung-galaxy-s-10

On my old j3 when I press the power button i get this cool transition/animation when the screen locks. The black thing that covers the screen vertically from the right and left side. Similar to how you get it with samsung tv but it does it from top and bottom.

Comment: Are you asking this from a developer's perspective? Development questions are off-topic here.

Comment: No the user should be able to do this normally from settings unless that feature is removed